# flutter error of Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch

Tags: flutter, ssl, connection

tried all solutions not working in my case -

getting this error in flutter -

Exception in thread "main"  Connection has been shutdown:

Answer (score 0):

sometimes network requests mismatch use VPN

Answer (score -1):

I think its a network issue , just use a VPN and run it again.

Comment: thanks for posting an answer! this answer might be spot on, but in trying to help the person answer this question, and future questions along the same lines, it's a big help if you can explain WHY you suspect this to be the case.  There's that saying, "give a man a fish and you'll feed him for a day, teach a man to fish and you'll feed him for a lifetime"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).